# Right Click Signal for Button gtkmm-3.0

Tags: c++, user-interface, button, gtkmm, right-click

is there any way to catch the right click signal in a button in gtkmm-3.0? If not, what widgets can catch the right click? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, connect to [`button-press-event`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Widget.html#aa1a2371482cc55309d13c6f828e190f2). The signal handler will receive a `Gdk::EventButton` object, which will tell you the mouse button that was clicked.

Comment: However, you might need to pass false as an extra parameter to connect(): https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-xeventsignals.html.en

Comment: The `Gdk::EventButton` will tell you whether it was a right click or not. There is no signal that is emitted _only_ on right clicks, and if there were, this is how it would work.

Comment: Here is an example, though in this example the default signal handler is overridden instead of the signal being connected: https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtkmm-documentation/tree/examples/book/treeview/popup/treeview_withpopup.cc#n69

I don't much like the 3 instead of an enum value, but at least it is documented: https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Event-Structures.html#GdkEventButton